# Qt and Tesseract Linkage

Tags: installation

How can i amend the pro file to make the program work?

Googled a lot about QT and Tesseract, could not find a solution yet.
Please advise

Code:

```
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    cout << ("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete api;
    delete [] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my pro file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = openCV
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\release\install\include

LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_core455.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_highgui455.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs455.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_imgproc455.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_calib3d455.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_features2d455.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_video455.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv\release\bin\libopencv_videoio455.dll
LIBS += -L"(C:\Program Files(x86)\Tesseract-OCR)" -ltesseract

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/tesseract

INCLUDEPATH += C:\Program Files(x86)\Tesseract-OCR)

LIBS += C:\Program Files(x86)\Tesseract-OCR)

LIBS +=-LC:\Program Files(x86)\Tesseract-OCR)
-ltesseract.dll
-llept.dll

LIBS += -LC:\Qt\opencv_cv2\OPENCV1\build-qt\lib
-lopencv_calib3d249d
-lopencv_contrib249d
-lopencv_core249d
-lopencv_features2d249d
-lopencv_flann249d
-lopencv_gpu249d
-lopencv_highgui249d
-lopencv_imgproc249d
-lopencv_legacy249d
-lopencv_ml249d
-lopencv_nonfree249d
-lopencv_objdetect249d
-lopencv_ocl249d
-lopencv_photo249d
-lopencv_stitching249d
-lopencv_superres249d
-lopencv_ts249d
-lopencv_video249d
-lopencv_videostab249d

SOURCES += main.cpp

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).